# Is there a chain rule for Taylor operators?

Tags: calculus, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, taylor-expansion, differential-topology

Given a commutative ring $R$, write $D_n(R)$ for the commutative ring $R[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^n.$

In this notation, the taking of degree $n$ Taylor polynomials can be viewed as a function $$T_n : \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow D_n(\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})), \qquad f \mapsto \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}}{i!}\varepsilon^i.$$

For example: $$T_2(x^5) = x^5+5x^4 \varepsilon+10x^3\varepsilon^2$$

It's well known that $T_n$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism; linearity is obvious, and the fact that $T_n$ preserves products is a fundamental consequence of the product rule. Long story short, I was wondering

> **Question.** Is there's a useful formula for the $n$th-order Taylor polynomial of a composite? As in: $$T_n(g \circ f) \;= \;\cdots$$

I've been stuffing around with this for about half an hour or so, but to little avail.

Comment: My first idea would be to express $T_n$ as $1+\varepsilon \partial + \frac12 \varepsilon^2 \partial^2 +\ldots + \frac1{n!} \varepsilon^n \partial^n$ (where $\partial$ denotes the derivative operator) and use Faà di Bruno's formula.